# In Python Pandas: How to reshape rows to columns without aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some trouble reshaping my DataFrame.

Just in case someone would like to reproduce the DataFrame:

```
data = {
    'timestamp': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01'],
    'id': [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000],
    'color': ['Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Pink', 'Pink'],
    'a': [4598, 1479, 3547, 9811, 8746, 9856],
    'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'c': [0.45, 0.89, 0.65, 0.06, 0.96, 0.46]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is an extract from my DataFrame.

```
    timestamp    id color     a  b     c
0  2021-01-01  1000  Blue  4598  1  0.45
1  2021-01-01  1000  Blue  1479  2  0.89
2  2021-01-01  1000  Blue  3547  3  0.65
3  2021-01-01  1000  Pink  9811  4  0.06
4  2021-01-01  1000  Pink  8746  5  0.96
5  2021-01-01  1000  Pink  9856  6  0.46
```

What I want is this:

```
             Blue                     Pink
    timestamp    id  a     b  c     a     b  c     a     b  c     a     b  c     a     b  c     a     b  c
0  2021-01-01  1000  4598  1  0.45  1479  2  0.89  3547  3  0.65  9811  4  0.06  8746  5  0.96  9856  6  0.46
```

I tried

```
df = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['timestamp', 'id'],
    columns= 'color'
)

df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
df.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace = True)
```

which gave me

```
color            Blue               Pink             
                    a  b         c     a  b         c
timestamp  id                                        
2021-01-01 1000  3208  2  0.663333  9471  5  0.493333
```

Unfortunately I do not want any aggregation. Is there a way I can achieve what I want?

Comment: You have duplicate entries in your columns; how do you intend to deal with those duplicates? The easiest way would be `df.set_index(['timestamp', 'id', 'color']).unstack()` but that won't work because of those duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to shape your df as you described. maybe there is a more straightforward way of achieving it. It feels strange to want a df in this shape, but I hope it makes sense for what you're trying to do

```
wide = (
    df.melt(
        id_vars = ['timestamp','id','color'],
        var_name = 'letter',
        value_name = 'value',
    ).set_index(['color','letter','id','timestamp'],append=True)
    .unstack()
    .unstack()
    .T
)

wide.index = wide.index.droplevel()
wide.columns = wide.columns.droplevel()

wide.loc['2021-01-01',1000]['Blue','a']
```

oops not actually what you want, here is what it looks like

[image]